# How to enable File Stream Support using SQL Server Management Objects?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, smo

I am trying to automate enabling `FileStream` on application startup. I have found SQL Server Management Objects SDK which is quite awesome. However, I am unable to find any such documentation with examples.

I really don't want application developers to keep setting environment with so many configurations.

Thanks!

**Update**

I have enabled FileStream using Server properties within SQL Server Management Studio, however, I am unable to do the settings in the service MSSQLSERVER's properties to enable FileStream using C#. I am using SQL Server Management Objects SDK and tried few things with WMI.

Comment: Hi @ImranFaruqi, Can you explain more detail about your question? Do you mean you want to enable FILESTREAM on the instance of the SQL Server Database Engine, or create a FILESTREAM-Enabled Database, or using the FileStream to read or write files?

Comment: Actually I have done the partial job.  I have enabled the FileStream using the server properties within Management Studio including query for creating database etc. However, I am unable to control the MSSQL Server service to enable file stream.